# HDD now saying partition must be formatted, trying to save data

Tags: hard-drive

My brothers hdd messed up on him. He said sometimes it would work sometimes it wouldn't.

I put it in an enclosure and connected it as an external. The first time it loaded right up. I unplugged it and changed computers, and now it's telling me to format.

Did unplugging it finish it off? I was not writing files, though I was immediately before looking into changing the ownership settings. Pretty sure I closed out of the ownership settings before unplugging..

The recovery partition still loads up fine. The Disk Manager says 911GB RAW, Healthy (Primary Partition)

**More info:**

The disk is clicking now. MiniTools partition recovery tools gets to 2% and crashes.

All I did was unplug it to switch from a laptop running Windows 8 to my desktop running Windows 7.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is the external enclosure.  Hook it up back in the original configuration then use a tool that displays the S.M.A.R.T data and share the results with us.

Comment: Unfortunately that laptop is now 8 hours away. I have another enclosure I can test with but this one is brand new and was working this morning. When trying to run Error-checking, it says it cannot access the disk.

Comment: All I did was unplug it to switch from a laptop running Windows 8 to my desktop running Windows 7. I've never had a partition just go RAW like this.

Comment: Just for the record and for anyone looking at this question in the future: If you're trying to recover data from a drive, DO NOT WRITE ANYTHING TO THE DRIVE AT ALL. You don't know how much longer the drive will work and some of the structures on the drive might already be corrupt. Trying to write to the drive has a very high chance of making things worse. In particular, running any recovery tool to recover by modifying the drive is a *bad* idea.